# Azure Functions Python v2: How to pass statuscode = 202 as HttpResponse without returning?

Tags: python, azure-functions, power-automate

I am using power automate's http request action to call an azure function, but the action times out after 2 minutes unless it is configured to use an asynchronous pattern and therefore need to pass a 202 response to power automate when the function is called. I cannot figure out how to pass func.HTTPResponse(statuscode = 202) without returning the function.

I've tried coding it without returning (shown below) but this doesn't work:

```
def auto_assignment(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    func.HttpResponse(statuscode=202)
    <misc code here>
    return func.HttpResponse(output_variable, status_code=200)
```

Comment: Look at using a webhook instead.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @Skin you can use webhooks or You can use below approach :

Firstly, azure function code:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import time
import json

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    time.sleep(150)
    res = "This is the response body content Rithwik."
    out = {
    "rithstatus": res  
    }
    response = json.dumps(out, indent=2)  
    logging.info(out)
    return func.HttpResponse(response, status_code=202)
```

In Logic app/Power Automate  **`design`**:

- In Design, you will call your function app and then delay your logic app workflow( wait) for some minutes so the function executes and you will get the log of the response.
- Then used the `Run query and list results` action.

  ```
  traces
    |where message contains "rithstatus"
    | order by timestamp desc
    | top 1 by timestamp
  ```

[image]

In code change runafter of delay like this:

```
"runAfter": {
                    "HTTP": [
                        "Succeeded",
                        "Failed"
                    ]
            }
```

[image]

If you keep failed even after failed the call has happened so response might not come to design but http call is posted so you will get logs.

**`Output:`**

[image]

This is how you can get response of long running azure function.